# SQL postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that I'm trying to perform below. However, being unable to test my query, I am unsure of my result.

The donors who have donated at least $10,000 since January 1, 2010 (donor ID, name, total
gifts).

```
SELECT   donor_id, 
         donor_name, 
         SUM (amount) AS total_gifts_since_2010 
FROM     donor 
JOIN     gift 
USING    (donor_id) 
JOIN     gift_fund_allocation 
USING    (gift_id) 
JOIN     fund 
USING    (fund_id) 
WHERE    gift_date >= ‘01/01/2010' 
GROUP BY (donor_id, donor_name)
HAVING   total_gifts_since_2010 >= 10000;
```

Either one of two things will happen:

1. What I want it to do, which is only adds amounts after 2010.
2. Not what I want it to do, which is add all the amounts, but only
   select/display the ones after 2010.

So my question would be something like this: Does the entire query happen instruction-by-instruction, or does the `WHERE` clause have an immediate effect on the query?

Comment: To filter something after `group by` you need to use `having` condition; also, your date format is not ISO compliant. If you want to test query but don't have postgres server installed, you could try http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: having is a where clause on an aggregate.  Instead of AND      total_gifts_since_2010 >= 10000  in the where clause, move it to having as having sum(amount) > 10000  (select,from,where,group,having is the order to use)

Comment: "However, being unable to test my query, I am unsure of my result." Why are you unable to test it? Install Postgres locally and generate some test data, or create a test schema on http://sqlfiddle.com Using an online Q&A site to test your code is an extremely inefficient approach to coding.

Answer (score 1):

1) WHERE should precede GROUP BY (in the statement)

2) The sequence is following: JOIN - WHERE - GROUP BY - SELECT list